# UIScrollView not properly adding subview in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add a UIView into a scrollview that I have. No bugs or errors, although nothing is showing up when running the code.

Which is:
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 667)

```
let newStory:InboxStory = InboxStory()
    newStory.titleLabel?.text = "test it"
    newStory.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667)

scrollView.addSubview(newStory as UIView)
```

Everything is created properly and my view has a label which is placed with autoLayout.

Here's my autoLayout for the label:
[image]

Right now, the UIScrollView remains empty (or at least looks blank). Is there something that I'm missing or not thinking about? Could my autoLayout be causing the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InboxStory is a subclass of UIView? And titleLabel is a subview of it? But in Storyboard you placed it as a subview of a scrollview in. Then added the view newStory (with an opaque white background) on top of it so that it completely fills the scrollview. So you know what's happening try replacing

```
scrollView.addSubview(newStory as UIView)
```

With

```
scrollView.insertSubview(view:newStory, belowSubview: newStory.titleLabel)
```

You should add titleLabel as a subview of newStory then making that a subview of scrollView.

Comment: Yes, InboxStory is a subclass of UIView and titleLabel is a subview of it (it' a label, but yes). Is there really no way to add just a general "container" view with all it's other subviews? I have to go through them individually and add each element? Thanks for the clarification, this was very helpful.

Comment: Those questions were more rhetorical, stating what you intend to do, but then pointing out what you've done. If you want to layout newStory in Storyboard drag out a uiview click on the identity inspector and change the class to InboxStory then add titleLabel as a subview (UILabel's are a subclass of UIView) of it. Or don't layout anything in storyboard and do everything programmatically. But just because a UIView subclass has a UILabel property doesn't mean one will appear without initializing it, setting it's frame, then adding it as a subview.

Comment: was just asking politely if there was a workaround. No need to get huffed up. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You're reading into things. I'm not put out, just explaining how the view hierarchy works.